# Is it possible to reflect whole Windows Forms applications?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

EDIT: The problem was a mismatch between the two programs' Framework versions: one was using 2.0 while two was using 4.0. The below code works perfectly.

I am trying to reflect a whole Windows Form application, but invoking the Entry Point does not work: either nothing happens or a crash shows up. Is  there something I can do?

```
public static void Reflect(object program)
{
    object[] objArray;
    MethodInfo entryPoint = ((Assembly)program).EntryPoint;
    MethodInfo methodInfo = entryPoint;
    if ((int)entryPoint.GetParameters().Length == 0)
    {
        objArray = null;
    }
    else
    {
        objArray = new object[] { new string[0] };
    }
    methodInfo.Invoke(null, objArray);
}
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a valid error description. What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Isn't faster Process.Start()?

Comment: Sorry. I expected it to start the program as it should start if I open it normally. Instead, either nothing happens or a crash appears.

Comment: Adriano I am trying to start the program without actually having it as a file on the disk (loading from memory).

Comment: You just...cannot. Within same process you can't have another message pump (don't forget it's single threaded). Write your assembly to disk in a temporary file then execute it with Process.Start(). No hope for something else.

Comment: It is not possible even if the only code my first application contains is the Assembly.Load and the Reflection (invoking)?

Comment: I'm posting a workaround but you should try it in deep, I don't know if it has drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If both your applications are WinForms then you can't run a second application within first one because it's a single threaded environment (and each one has its own message pump).

To workaround this issue you may start your second application from another thread. This way each *application* will run in its own thread (but honestly I don't know if this will always work or if there are other drawbacks with Windows).

Something like this (assuming your assembly has not been loaded for Reflection only):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate (object state)
{
    var entryPoint = ((Assembly)program).EntryPoint;
    entryPoint.Invoke(null, new string[0]);
});
```

Note that application entry point (if not `null`) will always have same signature, no need to check. Of course I wouldn't use a thread from pool but this is just an example.

Comment: My first application is not forms. In fact it doesn't use Windows.Forms at all. Is this somehow a problem to showing the form of the reflected application? Do I have to import something from it first?

Comment: @user3162835 no. If it's  not a WinForms application it should execute without any error (and no need for dependencies). What's the exception/error you get?

Comment: Never mind, I found out what was the problem! Sorry for taking all of your guys' time!